# Retrieving the instance of an already-registered service in Mvc Core .Net Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following code snippet in my application:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyInterface, MyService>();
services.AddSingleton<IYourInterface, YourService>();
```

Due to some environment initialization process, I have to be able to obtain the singleton instance of IYourInterface within Startup class to call the service to read a couple of configuration entries from a remote server and populate them. How can I achieve this goal considering the fact that I am using .Net Core's built-in DI framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this to create this instance manually up front as follows:

```
var service = new YourService();

services.AddScoped<IMyInterface, MyService>();
services.AddSingleton<YourService>(service);
```

Just as it is wise to separate the registration process from use (as the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection library correctly forces), this kind of separation is important between loading/building configuration and making the container registrations. Doing register-resolve-register is unsupported by libraries like MS DI, Autofac and Simple Injector, because it can lead to lots of complexity and [subtle bugs](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decisions.html#container-is-locked).